# Timed out error on bing sdk script

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing

I am using **BingMaps SDK** for managing locations on my application. I am having a problem with the map not showing from time to time.

**Reason**: abpBingLocations.js:241 GET https://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=initMap net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

My code looks like this:

```
function loadScript() {
   // use global document since Angular's $document is weak
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.src = '//www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=initMap';
   document.body.appendChild(s);       
}
```

Do any of you guys can help me how to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Perhaps try adding the async and defer attributes to the script tag. Here is a code sample that I used to test: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsV8CodeSamples/blob/master/Samples/Map/Lazy%20Loading%20the%20Map.html